# Why doesnt my <form> work with REQUEST but works with POST

Tags: php, html

Hello I have the following form that collects data entered and later I output it. It works just fine when I use POST but when I use REQUEST like the teacher said to do, the echo $word comes back empty. Any ideas guys? please?

```
 <Form name ="form1" Method ="REQUEST" Action ="">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="<?php echo $word ?>" Name ="word">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Submit">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$word = $_POST['word'];
$book = $_POST['book'];
}



?>
```

Comment: there is no `REQUEST` value for method attribute for `<form>`. The value accepted for method attribute is GET and POST

Answer (score 2):

There is no method called **`REQUEST`** on a Form. It should be either **`GET`** or **`POST`**

Maybe your teacher is confused with the **`$_REQUEST`** in PHP.

Comment: Sorry thank you I confused it with $_REQUEST from PHP

Comment: ^_^ `but when I use REQUEST like the teacher said to do` , so i came to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `GET`, not `REQUEST`.

`GET` will include the contents of the form submission in the URL itself, so it's suitable for things that should be able to be bookmarked, like search form submissions.

Here's more: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: Sorry thank you I confused it with $_REQUEST from PHP

Comment: For some reason only method=POST works. method=GET comes back with empty results. do you have any ideas why?

Comment: You have to use `$_GET['word']`

Comment: Figured it out changed 
<?php
if (isset($_GET['Submit1'])) {
$word = $_GET['word'];
$book = $_GET['book'];
}



?>
 from POST and it worked. damn what a noob i am
and u even beat me to it ty =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your teacher asked you this, but "REQUEST" is not a standard HTTP method so I don't think there's any shortcut in PHP to retrieve the data. I found that even using `PATCH` sometime causes problems.

What you could try is to read the raw data directly using:

`file_get_contents("php://input")`

Answer (score 0):

There is NO method named REQUEST. You can use only two methods : POST and GET.

If you are using POST as method, you can get the values using only POST OR REQUEST.

If you are using GET as method, you can get the values using only GET OR REQUEST.

For more information please refer to this page: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp